# How to solve this problem? I cant install samba in my Raspberry Pi 3 Always give error

Tags: linux, software-installation, ubuntu, samba

```
root@MyHome:/# sudo apt-get install samba
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  attr ibverbs-providers libboost-atomic1.67.0 libboost-iostreams1.67.0
  libboost-regex1.67.0 libboost-system1.67.0 libboost-thread1.67.0 libcephfs2
  libgfapi0 libgfrpc0 libgfxdr0 libglusterfs0 libgpgme11 libibverbs1
  libjansson4 libldb1 librados2 libtdb1 libtevent0 python-crypto
  python-dnspython python-gpg python-ldb python-samba python-talloc python-tdb
  samba-common samba-common-bin samba-dsdb-modules samba-libs
  samba-vfs-modules tdb-tools
Suggested packages:
  python-crypto-doc bind9 bind9utils ctdb ldb-tools ntp | chrony smbldap-tools
  ufw winbind heimdal-clients
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  attr ibverbs-providers libboost-atomic1.67.0 libboost-iostreams1.67.0
  libboost-regex1.67.0 libboost-system1.67.0 libboost-thread1.67.0 libcephfs2
  libgfapi0 libgfrpc0 libgfxdr0 libglusterfs0 libgpgme11 libibverbs1
  libjansson4 libldb1 librados2 libtdb1 libtevent0 python-crypto
  python-dnspython python-gpg python-ldb python-samba python-talloc python-tdb
  samba samba-common samba-common-bin samba-dsdb-modules samba-libs
  samba-vfs-modules tdb-tools
0 upgraded, 33 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,700 kB/24.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 94.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://mirror.ossplanet.net/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf samba-libs                                                                                         armhf 2:4.9.5+dfsg-5+deb10u1+rpi1 [4,700 kB]
Err:1 http://mirror.ossplanet.net/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf samba-libs                                                                                         armhf 2:4.9.5+dfsg-5+deb10u1+rpi1
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:ec54d60b1ed31f0b1f4b085ef6cbbe1f3a37be3a9996bc6eb2288925f0aaddb8
   - SHA1:f7f3c17a0d0c76caf6e797d444da76727a0cdf7a [weak]
   - MD5Sum:5e0ece95d440f67494bf9b5709e5a53d [weak]
   - Filesize:4699860 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:960fac362274a3e8bc0edf594a8f958f025d1844e5b3f45118bc6d57a36a8fa0
   - SHA1:103ff7ba03b5188db8f6ef5bfd345a7f086c80bc [weak]
   - MD5Sum:75d467bcf5d001fb50e0b8f351ba665d [weak]
   - Filesize:4699860 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Wed, 04 Sep 2019 19:57:38 +0000
Fetched 4,700 kB in 4s (1,070 kB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.ossplanet.net/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/s/sam                                                                                        ba/samba-libs_4.9.5+dfsg-5+deb10u1+rpi1_armhf.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:ec54d60b1ed31f0b1f4b085ef6cbbe1f3a37be3a9996bc6eb2288925f0aaddb8
    - SHA1:f7f3c17a0d0c76caf6e797d444da76727a0cdf7a [weak]
    - MD5Sum:5e0ece95d440f67494bf9b5709e5a53d [weak]
    - Filesize:4699860 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:960fac362274a3e8bc0edf594a8f958f025d1844e5b3f45118bc6d57a36a8fa0
    - SHA1:103ff7ba03b5188db8f6ef5bfd345a7f086c80bc [weak]
    - MD5Sum:75d467bcf5d001fb50e0b8f351ba665d [weak]
    - Filesize:4699860 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Wed, 04 Sep 2019 19:57:38 +0000
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-mis                                                                                        sing?
```

I tried all code such as **Sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade** **sudo apt install samba - -fix-missing** -y
still setting error Unable to fetch some archives,

Comment: Baffled you are logged on as root but still using sudo?  Are you running Buster?  If so can you `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and the first line should read deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi

Comment: @Andyroo The question is tagged with ubuntu

Comment: @Ingo - need lockdown to end so I can get new glasses I think...

Comment: Apart from the ubuntu tag, there is of course "raspbian buster/main armhf" and "2:4.9.5+dfsg-5+deb10u1+rpi1"  in the log.   Perhaps choose another raspbian mirror?  https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianMirrors

Answer (score 2):

@Bikram:

You need to delete your question, and ask it on [this SE](https://askubuntu.com/) site instead.

FWIW: You didn't indicate which version of Ubuntu you are using, but that may be an important point. Ubuntu is **similar** to Raspbian due to their shared Debian heritage, but they are different in many respects also. Your problem certainly *sounds like* an issue with the repos you are using - you might also mention that when you ask your question on the [Ubuntu SE](https://askubuntu.com/) site.